# Is there a difference between 'FETCH' and 'FETCH FIRST'?

Tags: sql, oracle

I currently am preparing for an Oracle SQL exam. I have some test exams to try. One question was as follows:

**Which query will generate the required result?**

There were two of the possible answers, I picked the top one. But the answer should have been the bottom one according to the exam.

```
SELECT employee_id, last_name, salary
FROM employees
ORDER BY salary DESC
FETCH FIRST 5 PERCENT ROWS ONLY;

SELECT employee_id, last_name, salary
FROM employees
ORDER BY salary DESC
FETCH 5 PERCENT ROWS ONLY;
```

Now I wanted to find out what the difference between **'FETCH'** and **'FETCH FIRST'** is, but so far I had no luck googling it, I only find pages that talk about **'FETCH FIRST'** in combination with **'FETCH NEXT'** and so on. But no luck so far in what I'm looking for.

Can anyone explain to me what the difference between **'FETCH'** and **'FETCH FIRST'** is? And if both are correct, why would the exam prefer **'FETCH'** over **'FETCH FIRST'**?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's simple: `FETCH 5 PERCENT ROWS ONLY` is invalid and will be rejected by Oracle. [As documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) you have to specify `FIRST` or `NEXT` after `FETCH`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That means that the answers to my exam are not what they should be, not the ideal situation, thanks ;). But I'm glad that I initially did pick the right answer.

Comment: Apparently the questions are intended to check if you know the syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it's better to try things out before you ask.

```
SQL>     with basis as (select level l,100 - level lm from dual connect by level <=100)
  2      select l, lm from basis order by lm fetch first 5 percent rows only;

         L         LM
---------- ----------
   100          0
    99          1
    98          2
    97          3
    96          4
```

So the first statement works.

Second one:

```
SQL>     with basis as (select level l,  100 - level lm from dual connect by level <=100)
  2      select l, lm from basis order by lm fetch  5 percent rows only;

Error starting at line : 6 in command -  
    with basis as (select level l,  100 - level lm from dual connect by level <=100)
    select l, lm from basis order by lm fetch  5 percent rows only
Error at Command Line : 7 Column : 48
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

So error message points out that after fetch something is missing. 
Or as pointed out by a_horse. Read the manual.

Comment: Good point, I think I could trust the exam, but apparantly not.

Answer (score 1):

Your exam is wrong, the correct query is the top one.

The FETCH statement is a PL/SQL statement that is used to retrieve rows of data from the result set of a multi-row query, and as such, cannot be used in a SQL query :
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems020.htm

The FETCH (NEXT | FIRST) statement is used in queries to retrieve only a certain number or rows from a result : https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljoffsetfetch.html

Answer (score 1):

The [`SELECT` Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABBADDD) contains the syntax for the row limiting clause:

[image: SELECT row limiting clause]

From this, the `OFFSET` and `FETCH` clauses are each optional; however if the `FETCH` clause is included then it must be immediately followed by the `FIRST` or `NEXT` keyword.

Thus the second query:

```sql
SELECT employee_id, last_name, salary
FROM employees
ORDER BY salary DESC
FETCH 5 PERCENT ROWS ONLY;
```

Is not syntactically correct as it is missing the `FIRST` (or `NEXT`) keyword.